# Oracle trigger syntax

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a question about my trigger that I'm trying to create between two tables.  When one table is updated the other should be updated too, but I seem to be missing proper syntax.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER TRIG_DEPT_ONUPDATE
AFTER UPDATE OF DEPT_ID ON DEPARTMENT FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    UPDATE TEAM
        SET DEPT_ID = :NEW.DEPT_ID
        WHERE TEAM.DEPT_ID = :NEW.DEPT_ID;
END;
/
```

I get errors on update ("integrity constraint (%s.%s) violated - child record found"), but using the code:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER TRIG_DEPT_ONUPDATE
AFTER UPDATE OF DEPT_ID ON DEPARTMENT FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    UPDATE TEAM
        SET DEPT_ID = :NEW.DEPT_ID;
END;
/
```

it changes every single row after an update, though only select few need the change.  Should an If statement be worked in somehow?

Comment: There is no Oracle 4.0.0.13

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To access the newly updated row values, you need a row level trigger not a statement level trigger:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER TRIG_DEPT_ONUPDATE
AFTER UPDATE OF DEPT_ID ON TEAM
for each row
BEGIN
    UPDATE DEPARTMENT
    SET DEPT_ID = :NEW.DEPT_ID
    Where DEPT_ID = :OLD.DEPT_ID;
END;
```

Comment: Oh, that changed all of my rows, but not the one needed, when using 'For Each Row'.

Comment: Thanks for the help, I still got the ("integrity constraint (%s.%s) violated - child record found") upon update, but then I just updated the other table and it worked out fine!

Answer (score 0):

I guess this row

```
DEPT_ID = DEPT_ID - :NEW.DEPT_ID
```

generates some DEPT_ID which is not existing. That's the error reason.